# PDF in UIWebView not showing digital signature

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am having a PDF file containing digital signature and other data but when I display the PDF in UIWebView digital signature is not visible, although other data is visible. If anybody know how make it visible please let me know.Thank you

Answer (score 2):

why you are using in `webview`. if you want to preview the PDF use `UIDocumentInteractionController`, it is easy to use, do like

```
  NSURL *URL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"sample" withExtension:@"pdf"];

if (URL) {
    // Initialize Document Interaction Controller
    self.documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:URL];

    // Configure Document Interaction Controller
    [self.documentInteractionController setDelegate:self];

    // Preview PDF
    [self.documentInteractionController presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
}
```

for [**sample tutorial**](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-previewing-and-opening-documents--mobile-15130)

Comment: Sorry dude but it is not showing me digital signature

Comment: http://hardcastlegis.co.in/PMC/SITE_PLAN_PDF/signed/AUNDH/AUNDH_101_1538.pdf   - This is my PDF link

Comment: bro in your PDF there is no signature is available ,

Comment: Check it on windows , it is also not showing on MAC

Comment: bro I checked in windows 7 the same answer bro : no sign is visible

Comment: Check it in Chrome, Some times Firefox is not showing Sign

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102341/discussion-between-alex-and-anbu-karthik).

Comment: it is showing on my windows PC yar, Not getting why this is happening , Lets continue discussion in Chat

Comment: it still doesnt display e-signature on the pdf file on UIWebView as well as UIDocumentInteractionController

Answer (score 1):

because apple does not fully support PDF digital signature. If you want to show pdf signature on iPhone,you should import a third pdf library such as mupdf,PSPDFKit.